# Router to Router Connection issue

Tags: networking, router, home-networking

Is it possible to use a switch to connect two routers using straight-through cable instead of using a cross-over cable to directly connect the routers?

Comment: Are you asking about Ethernet cables?

Comment: @grawity yes, i am asking if i can use straight through ethernet cable to connect two routers instead of crossover ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can; hubs & switches have the opposite wiring from hosts & routers *specifically* so that you could connect a host/router to a switch and vice versa. And since switches are transparent at layer 2, the routers won't notice any difference – they'll be exchanging the same packets either way.

However, modern routers **don't actually care** about straight-through vs cross-over cables anymore. As soon as you connect the cable, both devices figure out which pair arrangement they need to use. Automatic crossover (aka "Auto-MDIX") has been a popular feature in Ethernet devices for many years, and is now practically mandatory for Gigabit Ethernet.

So that means you *don't need* a switch to connect two routers (or two hosts) – you can just connect them using any kind of cable (but preferrably regular), and they will automatically work.

---

(IIRC, the 1000BASE-T 'Gigabit Ethernet' specification still includes a crossover cable, but in order to be compliant, it needs to have all four pairs crossed. Some cables, especially hand-made ones, were built for 100 Mbps Ethernet and only cross two pairs out of four, so they aren't up to spec. But *I think* most Gbit Ethernet ports will recognize and work with those, too.)

(On top of that, most "home routers" – the kind with dedicated WAN and LAN ports – actually integrate a switch as part of the device anyway, so the "LAN" ports would technically be wired as switch ports.)